# How to zoom in and scale uiimage

Tags: ios, uiimage

Im new to cropping images in Xcode, and in my app I take a picture, and put that picture into a uiimage that is in a circler form. What I want to do is zoom in or move the image while the image is in the circler view then save it to the final uiimage. What I have so far is

```
CALayer *imageLayer= imageView.layer;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius =imageView.frame.size.height/2;
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:.5];
[imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Please help as soon as possible! Im so confused.

Comment: What is your question about? How to crop and edit images? Or how to display them in UIImageView with round corners?

Comment: how to crop and edit them.

Answer (score 1):

Following code creates subimage from `rect` rectangle of `your_image` with zooming parameter `scale`

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([your_image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *subImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:your_image.imageOrientation];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: Author asked about moving image in UiImageView